# Lex And Yacc Infinite loop in my own loop statement

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I'm new in that content but I'm trying to create my own language and my looping style. here is my yacc file.

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);
int yylex();
#include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int symbols[52];
int symbolVal(char symbol);
void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val);
int evaluateComparison(int left, int op, int right);
%}

%union {int num; char id;}         /* Yacc definitions */
%start line
%token print
%token IF OPEN_PARENTHESES CLOSE_PARENTHESES OPEN_CURLY CLOSE_CURLY LOOP PLAS AND OR LESS GREATER LESSEQ GREATEREQ EQ NEQ
%token ELSE INC DEC PLUS MINUS MULTI DIVIDE ASSIGN MINAS SEMICOLON COMPARE LOGICAL_OPERATION MULAS DIVAS
%token exit_command
%token <num> number
%token <id> identifier
%type <num> line exp term 
%type <id> assignment
%type <id> operations
%type <num> conditions
%type <num> compare
%%

/* descriptions of expected inputs     corresponding actions (in C) */

line    : assignment SEMICOLON      {;}
        | ifstmt                {;}
        | loopstmt              {;}
        | exit_command SEMICOLON        {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
        | print exp SEMICOLON           {printf("Printing %d\n", $2);}
        | line assignment SEMICOLON {;}
        | line print exp SEMICOLON  {printf("Printing %d\n", $3);}
        | line ifstmt       {;}
        | line loopstmt     {;}
        | line exit_command SEMICOLON   {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
        ;
ifstmt : IF OPEN_PARENTHESES conditions CLOSE_PARENTHESES OPEN_CURLY line CLOSE_CURLY 
       | IF OPEN_PARENTHESES conditions CLOSE_PARENTHESES OPEN_CURLY line CLOSE_CURLY  ELSE OPEN_CURLY line CLOSE_CURLY 
       ;
conditions :
        exp compare exp { $$ = evaluateComparison($1, $2, $3); }
        ;
compare : EQ        { $$ = EQ; }
        | NEQ       { $$ = NEQ; }
        | LESS      { $$ = LESS; }
        | GREATER   { $$ = GREATER; }
        | LESSEQ    { $$ = LESSEQ; }
        | GREATEREQ { $$ = GREATEREQ; }
        ;


loopstmt : LOOP OPEN_PARENTHESES exp compare exp CLOSE_PARENTHESES OPEN_CURLY line CLOSE_CURLY 
            {
                int left = symbolVal($3);
                int right = symbolVal($5);
                while(evaluateComparison(left, $4, right)){
                    $8;
                }
            }



assignment : identifier ASSIGN exp  { updateSymbolVal($1,$3); }
            | operations
            ;

operations : identifier INC { $$ = symbolVal($1) + 1; updateSymbolVal($1,$$); }
            | identifier DEC { $$ = symbolVal($1) - 1; updateSymbolVal($1,$$); }    
            | identifier PLAS exp { $$ = symbolVal($1)+$3; updateSymbolVal($1,$$); }            
            | identifier MINAS exp { $$ = symbolVal($1)-$3; updateSymbolVal($1,$$); }
            | identifier MULAS exp { $$ = symbolVal($1)*$3; updateSymbolVal($1,$$); }       
            | identifier DIVAS exp { $$ = symbolVal($1)/$3; updateSymbolVal($1,$$); }   

exp     : term                  {$$ = $1;}
        | exp PLUS term         {$$ = $1 + $3;}
        | exp MINUS term        {$$ = $1 - $3;}
        | exp DIVIDE term       {$$ = $1 / $3;}
        | exp MULTI term        {$$ = $1 * $3;}
        ;
term    : number                {$$ = $1;}
        | identifier            {$$ = symbolVal($1);} 
        ;

%%                     /* C code */

int computeSymbolIndex(char token)
{
    int idx = -1;
    if(islower(token)) {
        idx = token - 'a' + 26;
    } else if(isupper(token)) {
        idx = token - 'A';
    }
    return idx;
} 

/* returns the value of a given symbol */
int symbolVal(char symbol)
{
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    return symbols[bucket];
}

/* updates the value of a given symbol */
void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val)
{
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    symbols[bucket] = val;
}
int evaluateComparison(int left, int op, int right) {
    if (op == EQ) {
        return left == right;
    } else if (op == NEQ) {
        return left != right;
    } else if (op == LESS) {
        return left < right;
    } else if (op == GREATER) {
        return left > right;
    } else if (op == LESSEQ) {
        return left <= right;
    } else if (op == GREATEREQ) {
        return left >= right;
    }
    else{
        return 0;  
    }
}



int main (void) {
    /* init symbol table */
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<52; i++) {
        symbols[i] = 0;
    }

    return yyparse ( );
}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

and this is my test.

```
loop(a==5){a=20; printbet a;}
```

in loopstmt I can not update value of left,right or $3,$5 that's why it is in infinite loop. I'm updating something in line state but even effect something I can not update values of $3 and $5. Could you help me to fix this error and create my own loop ?

Comment: OT: I recommend you split up the `line` rule to make it simpler, so `line` just becomes `statement | statement line`. Also note that I use *right* recursion instead of left recursion.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major flaw in your rule: You only evaluate everything *once*.

Take for example the part `exp compare exp`. That will fully evaluate both the `exp` non-terminals, and the results will be plain `int` values. Including the current value of the identifier `a`.

So no matter how many times you iterate your loop, no matter when or where you check the value of `$3`, it will never change.

Also note that because `$3` is the *value* of the variable `a`, you will likely pass an invalid argument to `symbolVal`, so it will never actually be found.

And again inside the code for the rule, you only evaluate the left and right parts of the condition *once* anyway. So no matter how many iterations you do, the values will be the same.

---

Instead of doing direct interpretation inside the rules, I suggest you go the "standard" way to create a tree-like structure, that is returned by each rule. Then add a new top-level rule which then recursively evaluates each sub-tree of the root-node.

There are plenty of examples and tutorials on how to do this.

Another possible solution is to separate values and variables. For example with a tagged structure like this:

```
enum type
{
    VALUE,
    VARIABLE
};

struct result
{
    enum type type;
    union
    {
        int value;      // Calculated values (when type == VALUE)
        int variable;   // Variable id (when type == VARIABLE)
    } val;
};
```

Then all rules return an instance of this structure, which you can then use to get either an evaluated value or a variable id.

Answer (score 0):

You have a general problem on interpreting input.  You have written all your statements to execute as soon as the rule interpreting them is known, but for conditionals, loops, and subroutine statements, you cannot hold this approach, becaquse you will execute the statements as they are parsed, and not as they should be, with the expressed program, so for example, in the loop body (independently of the boolean expression evaluation, which is evaluated only once, and the result applies at every loop body execution, making your loop to execute never, or always) and the loop will execute an infinite loop in case the expression (which is evaluated at interpretation time) results initially in a `true` result.

You cannot interpret the code as you show in your snippet (because you need first to reorder it, and this requires you to parse the full statement, to decide the orden in which statements must be executed), but you need to compile it to an internal form, that allows you to "execute" it later.  And make an execute on the toop of the parsing tree, that traverses the tree doing the actual evaluation of expressions to decide if the loop body has to be executed (descending with the execute() method) or not.

I recommend you to read the famous book of Prof. Ullman ["Compilers, principles, techniques, and tools"](https://www.google.com/search?q=compilers+principles+techniques+and+tools&oq=compi&aqs=chrome.0.35i39i355i650j46i39i650j69i64j69i57j69i60l2j69i61j69i65.2008j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  (also known as "The dragon book") to know how Lex and Yacc work internally, how information is gathered, how to process it, and how to execute it (includes full optimization chapters)  There's also a second edition, which includes examples in java and is deeply upgraded to modern compiling.  Any will be of much interest.  I have both :)